# How to extract parts of a log

Tags: text-processing

I have a log file which looks like this:

```
Event
Process 1
Process 2
End event success
Event 
Process 1
Process 3
End event error
Event
Process 1
Process 5
End event success
Event
Process 1
Process 7
End event success
Event 
Process 2
Process 4
End event error
```

I want to keep only the error events, like this:

```
Event 
Process 1
Process 3
End event error
Event 
Process 2
Process 4
End event error
```

I tried with `cat Event.log | awk '/Event/,/End event error/'` but that's not working as I want.

Comment: @TomNewton I have noticed that you tried two times to improve the question by adding more tags. Unfortunately, I and other reviewers had to vote to [reject](https://unix.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/442742) the suggestion both times because according to the site's guidelines and "best practices", tags shouldn't be used in that way: [awk] - Although the Q mentions `awk` as one attempt to solve the problem, it is not per se about how to use `awk` in a particular situation, so that tag shouldn't be used.

Comment: [wildcards] - The question doesn't revolve around the correct formulation of regular expressions or globs, so that tag doesn't apply either. [filter] - Although the question does involve filtering a text file, the tag's meaning is already included in the [text-processing] tag, so adding it would be a duplication. That said, efforts to improve the site's quality are always welcome, so please don't feel discouraged. You may want to look at [this Meta Q](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5838/re-tagging-text-processing-questions) on previous discussions the community had on the issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work:

```bash
awk '/^Event/{n=1} {lines[n++]=$0} /^End event error/{for(i=1;i<n;++i) print lines[i]}' Event.log
```

Explanation: we save all lines after 'Event' into an array, and print them when we encounter 'End event error'.

Answer (score 3):

Using `sed` to delete all the entries that you don't want to extract:

```bash
$ sed '/^Event$/,/^End event success$/d' file
Event
Process 1
Process 3
End event error
Event
Process 2
Process 4
End event error
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$ perl -l -n -e 'BEGIN { $/ = "\nEvent" };
                 print "Event$_" if /End event error/' input.log 
Event
Process 1
Process 3
End event error
Event
Process 2
Process 4
End event error
```

Using `\nEvent` as the Record Separator (`$/`), it prints records containing "End event error".

Note: in perl, the record separator is a case-sensitive, fixed string (i.e. not a regular expression).

If you want a blank line between each record (to make it easier to post-process as paragraphs), change the print statement to `print "\nEvent$_" if ...`.

Answer (score 1):

Using any awk:

```
$ awk '/^Event/{evt=$0; next} {evt=evt ORS $0} /End event error/{print evt}' file
Event
Process 1
Process 3
End event error
Event
Process 2
Process 4
End event error
```

Answer (score 0):

Using **Raku** (formerly known as Perl_6)

```perl
~$ raku -e 'for lines.join("\n").split(/ \n <?before Event >/) { .put if .words[*-1] eq "error" };'  file

#OR

~$ raku -e '.put if .words[*-1] eq "error" for lines.join("\n").split: / \n <?before Event >/;'  file
```

Raku is a programming language in the Perl family. Briefly,

1. Auto-chomped `lines` are read-in and joined with `\n` newlines. Here you can use `slurp` instead of `lines.join("\n")` if you don't care about adding an extra `\n` newline at the end of your output.
2. This data is `split` into records on inserted `\n` newlines that exist `<?before Event>` (positive lookahead).
3. Out`put` is determined `if words[*-1] eq "error"` which is to say, the `[*-1]` last whitespace-separated word of the record is "error". *[Note: you can return records with case-insensitive "error" anywhere in the record using: `if m:i/error/` instead].*

Sample Input:

```
Event
Process 1
Process 2
End event success
Event
Process 1
Process 3
End event error
Event
Process 1
Process 5
End event success
Event
Process 1
Process 7
End event success
Event
Process 2
Process 4
End event error
```

Sample Output:

```
Event
Process 1
Process 3
End event error
Event
Process 2
Process 4
End event error
```

Note, you can take a look at intermediates to make sure you're splitting on records correctly (drop the `if` conditional above and add `raku`):

```perl
~$ raku -e '.raku.put for lines.join("\n").split: / \n <?before Event>/;'  file
"Event\nProcess 1\nProcess 2\nEnd event success"
"Event\nProcess 1\nProcess 3\nEnd event error"
"Event\nProcess 1\nProcess 5\nEnd event success"
"Event\nProcess 1\nProcess 7\nEnd event success"
"Event\nProcess 2\nProcess 4\nEnd event error"
```

Just for fun, `join`/`split` on `\t` tabs for a really compact output (presumes no tabs in the input file):

```perl
~$ raku -e '.put if .words[*-1] eq "error" for lines.join("\t").split: / \t <?before Event>/;' file
Event   Process 1   Process 3   End event error
Event   Process 2   Process 4   End event error
```

https://docs.raku.org
https://raku.org